# How to replace <span class="italic"> with <i> with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have some HTML like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultricies nec erat ut ornare. <span class="it">Duis vel ante finibus</span>, vestibulum felis non, venenatis mi. Integer imperdiet eleifend placerat.</p>

<p>Aenean id mollis ligula, vel vestibulum ante. <span class="it">Nullam feugiat ex a mi fringilla, vitae semper dolor efficitur.</span> Phasellus et sollicitudin urna, at lacinia arcu. Curabitur orci justo, accumsan eu tempor sed, volutpat ac metus.</p>
```

How can I convert the `<span class="it"></span>` to `<i></i>`? I.e.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultricies nec erat ut ornare. <i>Duis vel ante finibus</i>, vestibulum felis non, venenatis mi. Integer imperdiet eleifend placerat.</p>

<p>Aenean id mollis ligula, vel vestibulum ante. <i>Nullam feugiat ex a mi fringilla, vitae semper dolor efficitur.</i> Phasellus et sollicitudin urna, at lacinia arcu. Curabitur orci justo, accumsan eu tempor sed, volutpat ac metus.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply rename the tags `name` and delete its `class` attribute:

```
for e in soup.select('span.it'):
    e.name = 'i'
    del e['class']
```

or in case that there are more attributes:

```
for e in soup.select('span.it'):
    e.name = 'i'
    for attr in list(e.attrs):
        del e[attr]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultricies nec erat ut ornare. <span class="it">Duis vel ante finibus</span>, vestibulum felis non, venenatis mi. Integer imperdiet eleifend placerat.</p>

<p>Aenean id mollis ligula, vel vestibulum ante. <span class="it">Nullam feugiat ex a mi fringilla, vitae semper dolor efficitur.</span> Phasellus et sollicitudin urna, at lacinia arcu. Curabitur orci justo, accumsan eu tempor sed, volutpat ac metus.</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('span.it'):
    e.name = 'i'
    del e['class']

soup
```

###### Output

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ultricies nec erat ut ornare. <i>Duis vel ante finibus</i>, vestibulum felis non, venenatis mi. Integer imperdiet eleifend placerat.</p>
<p>Aenean id mollis ligula, vel vestibulum ante. <i>Nullam feugiat ex a mi fringilla, vitae semper dolor efficitur.</i> Phasellus et sollicitudin urna, at lacinia arcu. Curabitur orci justo, accumsan eu tempor sed, volutpat ac metus.</p>
```